# Passing php array to python , doesn't work

Tags: php, python, arrays

I'm trying to send php array encoded as JSON to python script , it doesn't work .
Here's my code :

```
 <?php

    $data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');
    // $result = shell_exec('python /path/to/myScript.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
    $result = system('pythomPath/python scriptPath/myscript.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)).' 2>&1',$result);
    // Decode the result
    $resultData = json_decode($result, true);

    // This will contain: array('status' => 'Yes!')
    var_dump($resultData);
    ?>
```

python :

```
import sys, json
# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print ("ERROR")
    sys.exit(1)
# Processing
result = data[0]
# Sending (to PHP)
print (json.dumps(result))
```

Comment: I would ask you what error you're getting. But you won't ever see the error, because you've very cleverly swallowed *all* exceptions and replaced the useful error message and traceback with a useless "ERROR" message. Please, don't do that.

Comment: Try `print (sys.argv[1])` or a variation of that.

Comment: if you are sending `array('status' => 'Yes!')` as argument, then json.loads fails, since it ain't valid json.

Comment: It prints the (sys.argv[1]) fine , but it fails to execute json.loads(sys.argv[1]) , when I print it I get nothing .. and no error seen . 
now the code looks like :

`import sys, json
data=[]
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print (data)
except:
    print (sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(1)
result = data[0]
print (json.dumps(result))`

Sorry if code looks stupid , I don't write python I just want to process an array ..

Comment: Just remove try and raise and look what it says.

Comment: Final error after stackTrace `ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")`

may be I'm encoding the json somehow wrong , it's above in the php code , please check

Answer (score 0):

The data you're sending to `json.loads` is not a valid JSON, check it. If you want to convert that array to JSON, just use `json.dumps` as you did in the end of code.

But that isn't the only error. If you send this array as parameter as sys.argv, you'll not have expected result. If you send an array to this script, it will handle this param as a string.

Try this approach to handle it as an list, than to JSON.

```
data = eval(sys.argv[1])[0]

print (json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: It gives this error : 
`data = eval(sys.argv[1]) File "", line 1 [ as , df , gh ] ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: How are you using this script?